# Certificate remains in false state ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, azure-aks, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I have a dev and production environment for my project. Each environment is a namespace i.e dev codes run in the dev namespace of my cluster and production ready code runs in production namespace.

I have successfully deployed the applications and now need an Ingress Controller to access my application.

I am using nginx and letsencrypt to generate certificates.

Now I am not sure how it is supposed to be because I am using different namespace but here is what I did so far and I am not getting my certificate.

- I installed nginx-ingress in the default namespace with helm like this

helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx

nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller and nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission are added to my default namespace

I took the external-ip of the controller and added it to my dns record of the url I want to use.

- I installed cert-manager

  helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace default --set installCRDs=true --set nodeSelector."kubernetes.io/os"=linux

cert-manager and cert-manager-webhook are added to my namespace.

I created a ClusterIssuer in the default namespace too like this

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: MY_EMAIL
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

the ClusterIssuer shows as ready when I check it.

Then I created my dev Ingress for my dev namespace

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
  name: dev
  namespace: dev
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.dev.example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: api.dev.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/v1/user
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: accounts-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/v1/chat
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: chat-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Here is the response I have from my certificate description

```
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    api.dev.example.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-prod
  Secret Name:  tls-secret
  Usages:
    digital signature
    key encipherment
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2023-10-11T04:52:54Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
    Last Transition Time:        2023-10-11T04:52:54Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  tls-secret-xx
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                       Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                       -------
  Normal  Issuing    50m   cert-manager-certificates-trigger          Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  50m   cert-manager-certificates-key-manager      Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "tls-secret-xx"
  Normal  Requested  50m   cert-manager-certificates-request-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "tls-secret-xx"
```

Seems stuck in this state for a while and then Events become none.

I do not know if my steps are wrong or I am doing this wrongly. I am yet to run the production ingress because the dev does not work yet.

Any help on how to resolve this or a better approach for me please.

I am working on AKS.

error logs from cert-manager pod

```
1 service.go:43] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" "dnsName"="api.dev.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Service" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-c27w9" "related_resource_namespace"="dev" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret-xx-1483124881-xx" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I1011 15:50:14.645545       1 ingress.go:99] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" "dnsName"="api.dev.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Ingress" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-rw5pp" "related_resource_namespace"="dev" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret-8tcjs-1483124881-3055303561" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E1011 15:50:14.680729       1 sync.go:190] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '404', expected '200'" "dnsName"="api.dev.trydispatch.app" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret-8tcjs-1483124881-3055303561" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I1011 15:50:24.624193       1 pod.go:59] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensurePod "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver pod" "dnsName"="api.dev.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Pod" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-ncmjq" "related_resource_namespace"="dev" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret-xx-1483124881-xx" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I1011 15:50:24.624452       1 service.go:43] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" "dnsName"="api.dev.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Service" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-c27w9" "related_resource_namespace"="dev" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret-xx-1483124881-xx" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
I1011 15:50:24.624601       1 ingress.go:99] cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress "msg"="found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" "dnsName"="api.dev.example.com" "related_resource_kind"="Ingress" "related_resource_name"="cm-acme-http-solver-rw5pp" "related_resource_namespace"="dev" "related_resource_version"="v1" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret-xx-1483124881-xx" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E1011 15:50:45.392992       1 sync.go:379] cert-manager/challenges/acceptChallenge "msg"="error waiting for authorization" "error"="acme: authorization error for api.dev.example.com: 400 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection: 20.72.168.196: Fetching http://api.dev.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxx: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)" "dnsName"="api.dev.trydispatch.app" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret-xx-1483124881-xx" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"
E1011 15:50:45.472454       1 controller.go:98] ingress 'dev/cm-acme-http-solver-rw5pp' in work queue no longer exists
I1011 15:50:45.633571       1 conditions.go:192] Found status change for Certificate "tls-secret" condition "Issuing": "True" -> "False"; setting lastTransitionTime to 2023-10-11 15:50:45.633561001 +0000 UTC m=+144939.665284913
E1011 15:50:45.634116       1 sync.go:73] cert-manager/orders "msg"="failed to update status" "error"=null "resource_kind"="Order" "resource_name"="tls-secret-8tcjs-1483124881" "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1"
I1011 15:50:45.634153       1 controller.go:162] cert-manager/orders "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on orders.acme.cert-manager.io \"tls-secret-xx-1483124881\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="dev/tls-secret-xx-1483124881"
I1011 15:50:45.672640       1 trigger_controller.go:179] cert-manager/certificates-trigger "msg"="Backing off from issuance due to previously failed issuance(s). Issuance will next be attempted at 2023-10-11 16:50:45.000001 +0000 UTC m=+148539.031724912" "key"="dev/tls-secret"
I1011 15:50:45.702365       1 trigger_controller.go:179] cert-manager/certificates-trigger "msg"="Backing off from issuance due to previously failed issuance(s). Issuance will next be attempted at 2023-10-11 16:50:45.0000009 +0000 UTC m=+148539.031724812" "key"="dev/tls-secret"
```

New logs

```
I1011 16:33:08.290634       1 conditions.go:263] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "tls-secret-vbdfp" condition "Approved" to 2023-10-11 16:33:08.290624984 +0000 UTC m=+200.421811598
I1011 16:33:08.338929       1 conditions.go:263] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "tls-secret-vbdfp" condition "Ready" to 2023-10-11 16:33:08.338918852 +0000 UTC m=+200.470105566
I1011 16:33:08.367745       1 conditions.go:263] Setting lastTransitionTime for CertificateRequest "tls-secret-vbdfp" condition "Ready" to 2023-10-11 16:33:08.367733931 +0000 UTC m=+200.498920545
I1011 16:33:08.381767       1 controller.go:162] cert-manager/certificaterequests-issuer-acme "msg"="re-queuing item due to optimistic locking on resource" "error"="Operation cannot be fulfilled on certificaterequests.cert-manager.io \"tls-secret-vbdfp\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again" "key"="dev/tls-secret-vbdfp"
E1011 16:33:08.886887       1 controller.go:167] cert-manager/orders "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="the server could not find the requested resource (post challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)" "key"="dev/tls-secret-vbdfp-1483124881"
E1011 16:33:13.889603       1 controller.go:167] cert-manager/orders "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="the server could not find the requested resource (post challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)" "key"="dev/tls-secret-vbdfp-1483124881"
E1011 16:33:23.892202       1 controller.go:167] cert-manager/orders "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="the server could not find the requested resource (post challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)" "key"="dev/tls-secret-vbdfp-1483124881"
W1011 16:33:25.391910       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:33:25.391944       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Challenge: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:33:43.895592       1 controller.go:167] cert-manager/orders "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="the server could not find the requested resource (post challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)" "key"="dev/tls-secret-vbdfp-1483124881"
W1011 16:34:14.661845       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:34:14.661885       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Challenge: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:34:23.898404       1 controller.go:167] cert-manager/orders "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="the server could not find the requested resource (post challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)" "key"="dev/tls-secret-vbdfp-1483124881"
W1011 16:34:51.245547       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:34:51.245583       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Challenge: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
W1011 16:35:38.400411       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:35:38.400495       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Challenge: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:35:43.900733       1 controller.go:167] cert-manager/orders "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="the server could not find the requested resource (post challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)" "key"="dev/tls-secret-vbdfp-1483124881"
W1011 16:36:22.124074       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:36:22.124111       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Challenge: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
W1011 16:36:54.810068       1 reflector.go:424] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
E1011 16:36:54.810107       1 reflector.go:140] k8s.io/client-go@v0.25.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *v1.Challenge: failed to list *v1.Challenge: the server could not find the requested resource (get challenges.acme.cert-manager.io)
```

when I describe the certificate, I different resource name

```
Normal  Issuing    7m12s  cert-manager-certificates-trigger          Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  7m12s  cert-manager-certificates-key-manager      Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "tls-secret-72cxq"
  Normal  Requested  7m12s  cert-manager-certificates-request-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "tls-secret-vbdfp"
```

Comment: Have you check the logs in `pod/cert-manager-xxxx` pod in `cert-manager` namespace? This status does not tell much about what's going on

Comment: I got error

cert-manager/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="failed to perform self check GET request 'http://api.dev.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/mRxIpDsFLkHH89n_o4cAqj2Ivmm_o8vdjHaCAsWegIQ': Get \"http://api.dev.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxx\": dial tcp: lookup api.dev.example.com on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host" "dnsName"="api.dev.trydispatch.app" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret "resource_namespace"="dev" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01"

Comment: Not enough context to tell what exactly happened. Can you access the unencrypted version of your site (HTTP)? If not then a DNS record issue. Otherwise check ports 80, 443 are allowed for Ingres loadbalancer. Please follow this guide - https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-aks-letsencrypt/

Comment: No, I connect access unencrypted version. http//api.dev... returns a `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: `

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I added the new logs

Comment: "No, I connect access unencrypted version" that should be solved first. do you have the DNS records set correctly for the ingress load balancer IP?

Comment: Yes, I pointed the DNS to the External IP of the nginx loadbalancer. The error seems to have changed now though. Updating the question with the new logs because I delete the cert-manager and nginx and reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I could see you have annotated the ingress with `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer`. So, the `certmanager` is waiting for the `clusterissuer` to issue the certificate.
please double check the `clusterissuer` configuration?

For selfsigned certificate it should be like this.

```html
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
```